# XSLT 2.0 group by function showing repeating values in tag

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have followed the input XML and I am trying to implement group by logic. The problem is that it is repeating the value of the input " groups" tag in both of "groups" tag in the result.I am using xslt 2.0.

**Input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"?>

<jsonObject>
   <alarm>
      <groups>1</groups>
      <groups>2</groups>
      <typeKey>FIRE</typeKey>
      <longitude>0</longitude>
      <victim>2</victim>
      <letitude>0</letitude>
   </alarm>
   <token>{CE541}</token>
</jsonObject>
```

**Input XSLT:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 

     xmlns:cdm="http://com.example/abc/current/data" 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"

     >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

   <xsl:template match="//jsonObject/alarm">
  <cdm:Alarm>
    <cdm:Groups>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="//jsonObject/alarm" group-by="groups">

<cdm:Group> 
          <xsl:value-of select="groups"/> </cdm:Group>

</xsl:for-each-group>
    </cdm:Groups>
    <cdm:Latitude><xsl:value-of select="letitude"/></cdm:Latitude>
    <cdm:Longitude><xsl:value-of select="longitude"/></cdm:Longitude>
    <cdm:TypeKey><xsl:value-of select="typeKey"/></cdm:TypeKey>
    <cdm:Victim><xsl:value-of select="victim"/></cdm:Victim>
  </cdm:Alarm>
  <cdm:Token><xsl:value-of select="token"/></cdm:Token>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Current Result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <cdm:Alarm xmlns:cdm="http://com.example/abc/current/data"
           xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <cdm:Groups>
      <cdm:Group>1 2</cdm:Group>
      <cdm:Group>1 2</cdm:Group>
   </cdm:Groups>
   <cdm:Latitude>0</cdm:Latitude>
   <cdm:Longitude>0</cdm:Longitude>
   <cdm:TypeKey>FIRE</cdm:TypeKey>
   <cdm:Victim>2</cdm:Victim>
</cdm:Alarm>
<cdm:Token xmlns:cdm="http://com.example/abc/current/data"
           xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   {CE541}`</cdm:Token>`
```

**Expected Result:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <cdm:Alarm xmlns:cdm="http://com.example/abc/current/data"
           xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <cdm:Groups>
      <cdm:Group>1</cdm:Group>
      <cdm:Group>2</cdm:Group>
   </cdm:Groups>
   <cdm:Latitude>0</cdm:Latitude>
   <cdm:Longitude>0</cdm:Longitude>
   <cdm:TypeKey>FIRE</cdm:TypeKey>
   <cdm:Victim>2</cdm:Victim>
</cdm:Alarm>
<cdm:Token xmlns:cdm="http://com.example/abc/current/data"
           xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   {CE541}`</cdm:Token>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `current-grouping-key()` instead as following:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="//jsonObject/alarm" group-by="groups">
<cdm:Group>
    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
</cdm:Group>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code

```
<xsl:template match="//jsonObject/alarm">
  <cdm:Alarm>
    <cdm:Groups>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="//jsonObject/alarm" group-by="groups">
```

you are saying "every time I encounter an alarm, I want to process all the alarms". So it's not surprising you get repeated data in the output.